# Upsite down doesn‘t work

Tags: ios, view, controller

I've an tabbed application with four view controllers and also four ViewController.m/.h files. Upside down doesn‘t work although it is enabled in "settings".

```
//
//  FirstViewController.m
//


#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: You mean it's enabled in your project settings right? Make sure your device isn't orientation locked either.

Comment: Yes but still doesn‘t work.

Answer (score 0):

In your project/Deployment Info, you need to have marked the four options:

-Portrait
   -Upside Down
   -Landscape Left
   -Landscape Right